# Last DIV scrollable only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following scenario where i need to make a DIV scrollable.
Whats happening with me is when i try different solutions to make it scrollable the entire DIV set becomes scrollable. All i want to do here is make only the last DIV scrollable.

```
<div class="container">first</div>
<div class="container">second</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="notSoLong">Don't scroll this!!!!</div>
    <div id="long">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ut placerat ipsum. Integer mollis magna sapien, nec fermentum justo volutpat dapibus. In eget pretium enim. Scroll this!!!</div>
</div>

.container {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100px;
}

#long {
    width:200%;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `overflow:auto;` to `.container`.
Alternatively, if you want **only** the `.long` to scroll, you should wrap it with another element and set that to `overflow:auto`

Answer (score 0):

To make div scrollable you have to fix the height.
then overflow property will work. 
And for Last div to make scrollable you can use ":last" selector with class name in css

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by **CSS Selector**.

For Example :

```
.container:last-child {
    overflow-x:scroll; /* You can use 'auto' too, for showing Scrollbars when needed.
}
```

Another way to do it is by **jQuery/JavaScript**.

For Example :

```
$(function(){
    $("#long").attr(style="overflow-x:scroll;");
});
```

Check [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hardy_411/5j9becyo/)